# Gory horror movie: mermaid trapped in a freak show, eventually kills her jailor

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror, mermaids

I really can't remember much about this other than the very start, or at least I think it's the start...

The movie opens with a mermaid trapped in a huge tank of water, as part of some freak show I think. Eventually the mermaid kills the man keeping her captive.

It's a recent enough film, made in the last decade I reckon. American production. Pretty gory, lots of blood and guts I think.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Could this be *[She-Creature](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0274659/)*?

[image: woman's head in water, reflection shows a mermaid]

This film was released in 2001. It features a killer mermaid, as well as a freak show proprietor who wants to put her on display. According to [this review](http://mickeytgardener.tripod.com/id189.html):

> Ooh! Nicely done here. I like!!! He takes them to a very small tank
>   with a mermaid crammed inside.
>
> She's chained inside because she murdered drunk guy's wife. I guess
>   he's punishing her by leaving the algae build up in her tank.

So there is a mermaid in a tank. From the same review:

> Bummer. Now Angus is dead.

So, she also kills the person who kept her imprisoned.

Comment: It's actually not too bad for a "B" movie. Break out the popcorn and beverage-of-choice!

Comment: It's a decent watch! I love _creature features_. There just aren't enough monster movies these days...